# Angular material form validation and error not correctly displayed

Tags: angular-material

Form inputs error messages and form entries are not updated when the inputs are changed.

I tried to switch to form instead of ng-form, tried different kind of validations (required, email, pattern, ...) None seemed to change anything.

I am using
angular 1.7
angular-material 1.1.9
angualr-messages 1.7

This form is inside a table > tbody

```
<ng-form name="editedJiraForm">
<tr md-row ng-repeat="task in jira.tasks track by $index">
    <td md-cell>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input name="title" ng-model="editedJira.title" required>
            <div ng-messages="editedJiraForm.title.$error" md-auto-hide="false">
                <div ng-message="required">Title required</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </td>
    <td md-cell>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Description</label>
            <textarea name="description" ng-model="editedJira.description" md-maxlength="5000" rows="3" md-select-on-focus required></textarea>
            <div ng-messages="editedJiraForm.description.$error" md-auto-hide="false">
                <div ng-message="required">Description required</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </td>
    <td md-cell>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Priority</label>
            <input name="priority" ng-model="editedJira.ubi_priority" ng-pattern="/^(01|02|03)$/"/>
            <div ng-messages="editedJiraForm.priority.$error" md-auto-hide="false">
                <div ng-message="pattern">Invalid priority</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </td>
    <td md-cell>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Estimation</label>
            <input name="estimation" ng-model="editedJira.estimation" ng-pattern="/^\d+(.\d+)?$/">
            <div ng-messages="editedJiraForm.estimation.$error" md-auto-hide="false">
                 <div ng-message="pattern">Invalid estimation, use int or float</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </td>
    <td md-cell>
        <md-button ng-disabled="editedJiraForm.$invalid" class="md-fab md-primary md-mini" aria-label="validate" ng-click="editJira(selection.feature, $index, true)">
             <md-icon md-svg-src="static/images/validate.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-fab md-primary md-mini" aria-label="cancel" ng-click="editJira(selection.feature, $index)">
             <md-icon md-svg-src="static/images/cancel.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
    </td>
</tr>
</ng-form>
```

I expect to have
- The messages displayed when for instance the priority does not match the pattern.
- Similarly, when the form is invalid the validate button should be disabled.

Though in my case:
- The inputs fields do become red when the pattern or requirement is not respected but the messages do not show up.
- The validation button is always active.

When displaying the editedJiraForm in the html it is not updated as I edit the form, maybe a problem there ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok if anybody got a similar problem, I found an answer from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624341/how-to-validate-table-row-data-with-angular)

This was due because of the form being split into several  breaking it.

The solution was to remove the actual  element and replace it by using ng-form name="editedJiraForm" on the  element.

This gives the following code:

```
<tr ng-form name="editedJiraForm">
    <td md-cell>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input name="title" ng-model="editedJira.title" required>
            <div ng-messages="editedJiraForm.title.$error" md-auto-hide="false">
                <div ng-message="required">Title required</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </td>
    <td md-cell>
   ....
    </td>
</tr>
```